# Answers which are "faded"?

Tags: discussion

When I delete a post it becomes "faded". The black text becomes grey.

I have occasionally noticed other "faded" answers, vaguely wondered why they were faded, forgotten about them, then remembered but couldn't remember where they were so couldn't ask the question I am about to ask. Today, I have caught one!

In [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/713/can-we-lock-the-question-do-complex-numbers-really-exist) question, the last post is "faded", and on $-8$.

> My question is: is a large negative score the only reason a post becomes "faded"?

I would be interested to know if low-rep. users can see this post. I initially thought that there was some magical power that came with 2500+ rep. which allowed me to see posts users had recently deleted, but I suspect the above is probably more likely.

I have looked around a bit, and searched the faq, but cannot find an answer (or a reference to "faded" posts - but then, what do you search for when the thing you are searching for has no name other than the name you made up with vaguely fits the bill but not quite?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting a post does *not* make it become "faded".

Deleting a post hides the post from all users with <10K reputation (except for the question owner himself and moderators). Those who are able to see the deleted posts (owner, moderators, and 10K + users) will see the deleted post appear with a *pink* background, as opposed to the usual *white* background, indicating that the post is deleted.

Faded posts are those post with low scores. See [this discussion on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142320/155238).

Comment: Ah, it has been a while since I deleted a post. My memory is hazy. Thanks.